Need to show table using vega script
I want to show below data as table using vega script , I am building a dashboard in kibana and getting following response from elastic , now I need to render the below data as table, required columns are key,last_5_days.doc_count ,last_5_days.avg_time_taken_5d.value, today.avg_time_taken_today.value ,today.count_today
  [
        {
          "key": "com.ofb.core.events.custom.application.useractivity.UserActivityUpdateEvent",
          "doc_count": 835,
          "last_5_days": {
            "doc_count": 725,
            "avg_time_taken_5d": {
              "value": 72.96413793103449
            },
            "count_5d": {
              "value": 725
            }
          },
          "today": {
            "doc_count": 110,
            "avg_time_taken_today": {
              "value": 91.92727272727272
            },
            "count_today": {
              "value": 110
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "/api/v1/account/roledetail",
          "doc_count": 601,
          "last_5_days": {
            "doc_count": 572,
            "avg_time_taken_5d": {
              "value": 5.564685314685315
            },
            "count_5d": {
              "value": 572
            }
          },
          "today": {
            "doc_count": 29,
            "avg_time_taken_today": {
              "value": 4.551724137931035
            },
            "count_today": {
              "value": 29
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "/api/v2/getLoggedInDetails/admin",
          "doc_count": 521,
          "last_5_days": {
            "doc_count": 494,
            "avg_time_taken_5d": {
              "value": 52.61943319838057
            },
            "count_5d": {
              "value": 494
            }
          },
          "today": {
            "doc_count": 27,
            "avg_time_taken_today": {
              "value": 8.925925925925926
            },
            "count_today": {
              "value": 27
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "/api/v1/permissions",
          "doc_count": 454,
          "last_5_days": {
            "doc_count": 428,
            "avg_time_taken_5d": {
              "value": 18.13785046728972
            },
            "count_5d": {
              "value": 428
            }
          },
          "today": {
            "doc_count": 26,
            "avg_time_taken_today": {
              "value": 13.692307692307692
            },
            "count_today": {
              "value": 26
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "/api/v2/productCategory/categoryData",
          "doc_count": 434,
          "last_5_days": {
            "doc_count": 397,
            "avg_time_taken_5d": {
              "value": 167.79596977329976
            },
            "count_5d": {
              "value": 397
            }
          },
          "today": {
            "doc_count": 37,
            "avg_time_taken_today": {
              "value": 225.75675675675674
            },
            "count_today": {
              "value": 37
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "/api/v1/permissions/user",
          "doc_count": 433,
          "last_5_days": {
            "doc_count": 407,
            "avg_time_taken_5d": {
              "value": 8.498771498771498
            },
            "count_5d": {
              "value": 407
            }
          },
          "today": {
            "doc_count": 26,
            "avg_time_taken_today": {
              "value": 9.461538461538462
            },
            "count_today": {
              "value": 26
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "/api/v1/account/findByEmailOrMobile",
          "doc_count": 197,
          "last_5_days": {
            "doc_count": 86,
            "avg_time_taken_5d": {
              "value": 5.22093023255814
            },
            "count_5d": {
              "value": 86
            }
          },
          "today": {
            "doc_count": 111,
            "avg_time_taken_today": {
              "value": 4.828828828828829
            },
            "count_today": {
              "value": 111
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "/api/v1/account/login/token",
          "doc_count": 167,
          "last_5_days": {
            "doc_count": 154,
            "avg_time_taken_5d": {
              "value": 15.103896103896103
            },
            "count_5d": {
              "value": 154
            }
          },
          "today": {
            "doc_count": 13,
            "avg_time_taken_today": {
              "value": 32.30769230769231
            },
            "count_today": {
              "value": 13
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "/api/v1/inventory/warehouse/lot/{inventoryLotId}",
          "doc_count": 126,
          "last_5_days": {
            "doc_count": 125,
            "avg_time_taken_5d": {
              "value": 86.784
            },
            "count_5d": {
              "value": 125
            }
          },
          "today": {
            "doc_count": 1,
            "avg_time_taken_today": {
              "value": 23
            },
            "count_today": {
              "value": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "/admin/api/v2/rfq/{rfqId}/summary",
          "doc_count": 117,
          "last_5_days": {
            "doc_count": 107,
            "avg_time_taken_5d": {
              "value": 245.80373831775702
            },
            "count_5d": {
              "value": 107
            }
          },
          "today": {
            "doc_count": 10,
            "avg_time_taken_today": {
              "value": 217.4
            },
            "count_today": {
              "value": 10
            }
          }
        }
      ]

I have tried enough but not getting any examples and showing errors only when I am trying if  anyone can share a working script or any example of showing table would also be helpful
thanks in advance
